# Combining a VIEW and TABLE

Tags: mysql

These are my codes for creating view is working fine for me, I just want to add one more field name:job_type which is from a table called Job Type.

So basically, I just want to combine VIEW:**vinvoices** and TABLE:**tjobtypes**

My Codes:

```
CREATE VIEW vinvoicesbymthbyjob 
as 
select 
`vinvoices`.`yymm` AS `yymm`,
`vinvoices`.`location` AS `job_location`,
`vinvoices`.`job_no` AS `job_no`,
format(sum(`vinvoices`.`amount`),0) AS `amount` from `vinvoices`
```

**TJOBTYPES**

- type_no
- type_name

**TJOBS**

- job_no
- job_name
- value
- start_date
- completion_date
- duration_mths
- type_no
- manager_no
- client_no
- location
- status
- notes

**VINVOICES**

- id
- date
- job_no
- job_name
- client_name
- amount
- ppaid
- inv_no
- prob
- notes
- contact
- location
- yymm

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You got to use `JOIN` : [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). What is the structure of `tjobtypes` table ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, I've added the structure, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my previous comment, you got to join tables. [Here is the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). A view is nothing more than a query, but it's usable like a table :

```
SELECT 
    vinvoices.yymm AS yymm,
    vinvoices.location AS job_location,
    vinvoices.job_no AS job_no,
    format(sum(vinvoices.amount),0) AS amount,
    tjobtypes.type_name AS job_type
FROM vinvoices 
JOIN tjobs ON tjobs.job_no = vinvoices.job_no
JOIN tjobtypes ON tjobtypes.type_no = tjobs.type_no
```

Comment: Ah, Got the logic now, Thank you so much! :)